# Worlight_DirectUpdate_pushNotification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Hi we are developing IBM Mobile First Platform 7.0 Hybrid Application,we are able to notify the user when the direct updates are available through worklight console as well when we are going to disable the version also we are notifying the user through worklight console.

Here my question is it mandatory to use Push Notification to notify the user regarding direct updates and version disabling or we can use worklight console to Notify the user about the updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default there is no push notification in order to notify of an impending Direct Update. So to answer your question, no it is not mandatory.

Plus, I am not even sure how would it be possible, since the Direct Update will happen only once the admin deployed a newer .wlapp to the server.

Comment: Thank you Idan your answer gave me clarity

Comment: a small doubt we can also trigger direct updates by using direct update realm in my application,at that point can't we sent push notification

Comment: I don't understand the question. The Direct Update *is* controlled by its realm. Direct Update happens only during runtime.